# Eclipse - Scala - Play - Macro Expansion error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, scala-ide, playframework-2.6, play-json

I have defined play json Read on certain case classes

```
object AccDataResponse {
  implicit val AccDataReads = Json.reads[Account] //compile error here
}
```

I am getting following warning on line `Json.reads[Account]` in eclipse ide with scala plugin. Project compile fine from maven command line using `mvn install`. Eclipse seems to treating it as an compilation error with red underline. It causes scala/eclipse code assist and other functionality to not work properly.
How can I get rid of it or disable it? e.g. Tell Eclipse/ScalaIDE not to treat is as compilation error because it is not.

> exception during macro expansion: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.tl$1()Lscala/collection/immutable/List; at play.api.libs.json.JsMacroImpl$CaseClass$1$$anonfun$play$api$libs$json$JsMacroImpl$CaseClass$$applies$1.apply(JsMacroImpl.scala:329) at play.api.libs.json.JsMacroImpl$CaseClass$1$$anonfun$play$api$libs$json$JsMacroImpl$CaseClass$$applies$1.apply(JsMacroImpl.scala:325) at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:335) at play.api.libs.json.JsMacroImpl$CaseClass$1.play$api$libs$json$JsMacroImpl$CaseClass$$applies$lzycompute(JsMacroImpl.scala:325) at play.api.libs.json.JsMacroImpl$CaseClass$1.play$api$libs$json$JsMacroImpl$CaseClass$$applies(JsMacroImpl.scala:318) at play.api.libs.json.JsMacroImpl$CaseClass$1.(JsMacroImpl.scala:349) at play.api.libs.json.JsMacroImpl.macroCaseImpl$1(JsMacroImpl.scala:621) at play.api.libs.json.JsMacroImpl.macroImpl(JsMacroImpl.scala:790) at play.api.libs.json.JsMacroImpl.implicitConfigReadsImpl(JsMacroImpl.scala:38) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor668.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.JavaReflectionRuntimes$JavaReflectionResolvers.$anonfun$resolveJavaReflectionRuntime$4(JavaReflectionRuntimes.scala:34) at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.JavaReflectionRuntimes$JavaReflectionResolvers$$Lambda$5234/1495203213.apply(Unknown Source) at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.macroExpandWithRuntime(Macros.scala:772)